# nodejs, get locale of OS

Tags: node.js

in python with `getdefaultlocale` I can get the locale

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('es_ES', 'UTF-8')
```

in nodejs exists some similar?

Comment: `process.env.LANG` ? It may work on UNIX systems

Comment: @AdriánArroyoCalle yes, this was the first solution I found ... maybe exist a more general ...

Comment: @AdriánArroyoCalle, `process.env.LANG` does not exist in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not as straightforward as it seems. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html) tells the whole story. There's also [os-locale](https://github.com/sindresorhus/os-locale) that it might be helpful.

But if you happen to be running a simulated browser environment, you can try this:
`console.log('navigator.language:', navigator.language);`

Comment: os-locale has been changed to an ESM only library which excludes it from being used in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method.

```js
const locale = (process.env.LANG || process.env.LANGUAGE || process.env.LC_ALL || process.env.LC_MESSAGES).split('.')[0]

console.log(locale)
```

Which should work on Windows and Linux, hopefully Mac as well though I didn't test that.

Note that if doing this on 1 line as illustrated, you might want to wrap it in a try/catch just in case you get an env response that doesn't have a "." in it.